# PHP csv file has only one column

Tags: php, csv

i try to download a csv file, but when i download it, my data are only in one column.

I have

```
[1,2,3,4,5] [] [] [] []
```

And i need

```
[1] [2] [3] [4] [5]
```

My code :

```
function to_csv($tab){
$Allarray=array();
foreach ($tab as $tableau){
    $Allarray[]=$tableau;
}

$separateur = "\t";
$entete = array('firstname', 'name', 'mail', 'rate','review','review_date','order_ref', 'oder_date', 'source');


$file = implode($separateur, $entete) . "\r\n";

foreach ($Allarray as $ligne) {
    $file .= implode($separateur, $ligne) . "\r\n";
}

header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=ebay_export_'.date("dmYHis").'.csv');
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
header('Expires: 0');
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
header('Pragma: public');
print chr(239) . chr(187) . chr(191) .($file);
exit;
```

}

edit : 
My values for tab is the data foreach column :

```
 array (size=36)
  0 => 
    array (size=9)
      'firstname' => 
        object(SimpleXMLElement)[9]
          public 0 => string 'mywifemademe' (length=12)
      'name' => string ' ' (length=1)
      'mail' => string 'anonymous@anonymous.com' (length=23)
      'rate' => int 5
      'review' => 
        object(SimpleXMLElement)[12]
          public 0 => string 'WONDERFUL-FAST PAYMENT-GREAT COMMUNICATION-FIRST CLASS! A+A+' (length=60)
      'review_date' => 
        object(SimpleXMLElement)[13]
          public 0 => string '2002-06-08T18:29:31.000Z' (length=24)
      'order_ref' => string '1539157020_EBAY_2018-03-13 15:21:40_0' (length=37)
      'order_date' => 
        object(SimpleXMLElement)[19]
          public 0 => string '2002-06-08T18:29:31.000Z' (length=24)
      'source' => string '12' (length=2)
  1 => 
  ...
```

But when i download the .csv, in my excel, all this data are in column "A" :

```
    firstname   name    mail    rate    review  review_date order_ref order_date source

mywifemademe anonymous@anonymous.com WONDERFUL-FAST PAYMENT-GREAT COMMUNICATION-FIRST CLASS! A+A+ ...
```

Comment: And what are the contents of the file?

Comment: _“I have [1,2,3,4,5] [] [] [] []”_ - is that the actual _file content_, or what you see after you opened this in Excel?

Comment: And what is the value of `$tab`?  Per @FedericoklezCulloca we can _guess_ tab, but you haven't shared that with us, so it's just a guess...

Comment: Are you watching your CSV file in Excel? Excel uses a semicolon as a separator by default. If you use another one (in your example \t) you need to tell Excel by using the Data >> Text to columns function

Comment: i have edit my post for more explain

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change the separator to ';'; i got same issues before because you are excel to read it .

Comment: Not all heroes wear capes 